# Call a function after rendering Ext.view.View

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to call a function after rendering Ext.view.View?

```
Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('imagesStore'),
tpl: imageTpl,
itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',
emptyText: 'No images available',
renderTo: Ext.getBody()});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the afterrender event like so:

```
Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('imagesStore'),
    tpl: imageTpl,
    itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',
    emptyText: 'No images available',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
           // Do something here
        }
    }
});
```

You can access the documentation for that [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.View-event-afterrender)